# Модальные окна и динамические списки

Tags: javascript

Надо сделать подобное. Я подобное сделал, но это получается говнокод какой-то и обслуживать его тоже вредно.  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
onst coise = {
    category: '',
    subcategory: '',
    oneparams: '',
    twoparams: '',
    photo: ''
}


const categories = [
    "Работа", "Транспорт", "Недвижимость", "Услуги", "Электроника"
];

const categoriesList = document.getElementsByClassName('categoryList')[0];
const imgStrelka = document.getElementsByClassName('imgStrelka')[0];

const categorie = {
    "Работа": {
        subcategory: {
            title: "Выберите подкатегорию",
            categorii: ["Вакансии", "Резюме", "Подработка"],
        },
        
        photo: {
            title: "Загрузить изображение",
            categorii: ["Выбрать", "Сфотографировать", "У меня нет фото"]
        }
    },
    "Транспорт": {
        subcategory: {
            title: "Выберите подкатегорию",
            categorii: ["Авто", "Мото", "Велосипеды"],
        },
        oneparams: {
            title: "Какая марка?",
            categorii: ["бмв", "ауди", "мерседес", "бентли", "лада"],
        },


        photo: {
            title: "Загрузить изображение",
            categorii: ["Выбрать", "Сфотографировать", "У меня нет фото"]
        }
    }, 
    "Недвижимость": {
        subcategory: {
            title: "Выберите подкатегорию",
            categorii: ["Квартира", "Дом", "Комната", "Гараж", "Земельный участок"]
        },
        oneparams: {
            title: "Сколько комнат?",
            categorii: ["Студия", "1", "2", "3", "4+"]
        },
        twoparams: {
            title: "Какой этаж?",
            categorii: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
        },
        photo: {
            title: "Загрузить изображение",
            categorii: ["Выбрать", "Сфотографировать", "У меня нет фото"]
        }
    },
    "Услуги": {
        subcategory: {
            title: "Выберите подкатегорию",
            categorii: ["Оказать услугу", "Требуется услуга"]
        },
        photo: {
            title: "Загрузить изображение",
            categorii: ["Выбрать", "Сфотографировать", "У меня нет фото"]
        }
    }
};






function addBoard(categor, tmp, title) {
    createLiAppend(categor, title); 
    addEventClick(categor, tmp);
}

function createLiAppend(arr, title) {
    for (let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerText = arr[i];
        li.classList.add('categoryItem');
        categoriesList.appendChild(li);
        contentTitle.innerText = title;
    }
}

/* удаляет все элементы li */
function deleteLi() {  
    categoriesList.innerHTML = ''
}


var contentTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('contentTitle')[0];

function addEventClick(arr, tmp) {
    const li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (let i = 0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        li[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (tmp === 'Категория') {
                contentTitle.innerText = "Категория";
                coise.category = li[i].innerText;
                deleteLi();
                addBoard(categorie[coise.category].subcategory.categorii, 'Субкатегория', categorie[coise.category].subcategory.title);
            }
            else if (tmp === "Субкатегория") {
                coise.subcategory = li[i].innerText;
                deleteLi();
                
                if (categorie[coise.category].oneparams === undefined) {
                    addBoard(categorie[coise.category].photo.categorii, 'Фото', categorie[coise.category].photo.title);
                } else 
                addBoard(categorie[coise.category].oneparams.categorii, '1 параметр', categorie[coise.category].oneparams.title);
                
            }
            else if (tmp === '1 параметр') {

                coise.oneparams = li[i].innerText;
                deleteLi();

                if (categorie[coise.category].twoparams === undefined) {
                    addBoard(categorie[coise.category].photo.categorii, 'Фото', categorie[coise.category].photo.title);
                } else 
                addBoard(categorie[coise.category].twoparams.categorii, '2 параметр', categorie[coise.category].twoparams.title);

            }
            else if (tmp === '2 параметр') {
                coise.twoparams = li[i].innerText;
                deleteLi();
                addBoard(categorie[coise.category].photo.categorii, 'Фото', categorie[coise.category].photo.title)
            } 
            else if (tmp === 'Фото') {
                if (li[i].innerText === 'У меня нет фото') window.location.reload();
                
            }
        })
    }   
}
```

Comment: Может есть какой-нибудь альтернативный вариант? или скажите куда копать

Comment: первое, что я бы сделал - заменил проверку по слову, вместо этого можно добавить какой-нибудь `data-*` аттрибут и по нему разруливать, т.к. если возникнет необходимость в мультиязычности, то пиши - пропало и из этого вытекает, что можно сильно разгрузить функцию `addEventClick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью затачивать под указанные Вами скриншоты не стал, но общую логику обрисовал.

```js
let activeScreen = 0;
let screenValues = {};

const $screen = document.getElementById('screen');
const $screenOptions = document.getElementById('screen-options');
const $screenLabel = document.getElementById('screen-label');

// Список экранов и их параметров
let screens = [{ 
  key: 'key1',
  label: 'Заголовок 1', 
  options: [ 
    {label: 'Параметр 1-1', value: 'value1-1' },
    {label: 'Параметр 1-2', value: 'value1-2' },
    //...
  ] 
},{ 
  key: 'key2',
  label: 'Заголовок 2', 
  options: [ 
    {label: 'Параметр 2-1', value: 'value2-1' },
    {label: 'Параметр 2-2', value: 'value2-2' },
    {label: 'Параметр 2-3', value: 'value2-3' },
    //...
  ] 
}];

// Функция обновления активного экрана
function updateScreen(screenIndex) {
  
  // Переключаемся на следующий экран
  activeScreen = screenIndex;

  // Обновляем заголовок нового экрана
  $screenLabel.innerText = screens[activeScreen].label;
  
  // Обновляем параметры нового экрана
  $screenOptions.innerHTML = '';
  const options = screens[activeScreen].options;
  for (const optionIndex in options) {
    let $option = document.createElement('li');
    $option.innerText = options[optionIndex].label;
    $option.onclick = () => onSelectScreenOption(optionIndex);
    $screenOptions.appendChild($option);
  }
  
}

// Событие выбора параметра активного экрана
function onSelectScreenOption(optionIndex) {

  const activeScreenData = screens[activeScreen];
  const selectedOption = activeScreenData.options[optionIndex];
 
  // Сохраняем значение выбранного параметра
  screenValues[activeScreenData.key] = selectedOption.value;
  
  if (activeScreen + 1 === screens.length) { 
    // Выбор параметров завершен
    // Скрываем экран
    $screen.style.display = 'none'; 
    // Все значения экранов хранятся в объекте screenValues
    console.log(screenValues); 
  } else {
    updateScreen(activeScreen + 1);
  }
  
}

updateScreen(0); // Показваем первый экран
```

```html
<div id='screen'>
  <h2 id='screen-label'></h2>
  <ul id='screen-options'></ul>
</div>
```